# How to get a list of Jobs created by ScaledJob?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs, keda, keda-scaledjob

How can I get a list of Kubernetes [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) created by a particular [`ScaledJob`](https://keda.sh/docs/concepts/scaling-jobs/#scaledjob-spec) object?

Answer (score 0):

When KEDA creates Jobs as a result of a `ScaledJob` object, it also adds [a set of labels](https://github.com/kedacore/keda/blob/4da3a5ba9bb66334b1293ebbeb9eceae2b7a97b8/pkg/scaling/executor/scale_jobs.go#L129-L135) to the Job.

```golang
labels := map[string]string{
    "app.kubernetes.io/name":       scaledJob.GetName(),
    "app.kubernetes.io/version":    version.Version,
    "app.kubernetes.io/part-of":    scaledJob.GetName(),
    "app.kubernetes.io/managed-by": "keda-operator",
    "scaledjob.keda.sh/name":       scaledJob.GetName(),
}
```

This allows you to use `kubectl get jobs` with the `-l, --selector=''` option to filter jobs by label.

```
-l, --selector='':
    Selector (label query) to filter on, supports '=', '==', and '!='.(e.g. -l key1=value1,key2=value2). Matching
    objects must satisfy all of the specified label constraints.
```

For example, for a `ScaledJob` named `foo`:

```bash
$ kubectl get jobs --selector='scaledjob.keda.sh/name=foo'
NAME        COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
foo-cjgds   1/1           7m11s      27m
foo-rwrtx   0/1           41m        41m
```

Likewise, you can get *all* Jobs created by KEDA by selecting based on the `app.kubernetes.io/managed-by` label:

```bash
$ kubectl get jobs --selector='app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=keda-operator'
```